# What is wrong is this code?

Tags: c, data-structures

I need help with the code below.

```
typedef struct orders
{
    int quantity;
    char foodname[50];
} ORDER;

ORDER *ptr;

typedef struct Table
{
    int tableno;
    int priority;
    ORDER *orders;
    struct Table *next;
} TABLE;

TABLE *head, *s;
int n = 0;

int insert(int tablenum, int prio, char foodname[], int qty)
{
    TABLE *newO, *temp, *temp2;
    newO = (TABLE*)malloc(sizeof(TABLE));
    newO->tableno = tablenum;
    newO->priority = prio;
    strcpy(newO->orders->foodname, foodname);
    newO->orders->quantity = qty;
       //more code here...
}
```

In main function of this program, the user will be asked to what table number, priority number, name of the food they want to order and the quantity of the food they order.

There is also a showlist function this code, it will print out all the data on the list starting from the highest priority to lowest.

Now my problem is that, for example I already have two different transaction, what happens is that my second transaction copies the "foodname" and "quantity" of my 1st transaction.

Please help me guys.

Comment: Is `Table->orders` meant to be a pointer to a single `Order` entry or an array of elements? Also your struct and tag naming is inconsistent which will lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TABLE *newO = (TABLE*)malloc(sizeof(TABLE));
```

allocates memory for `TABLE`, but not for `orders`, which after this `malloc` call is just an uninitialized pointer so this line:

```
newO->orders->quantity = qty;
```

invokes an *undefined behavior*. You need to allocate the memory for orders as well, for example:

```
TABLE *newO = (TABLE*)malloc(sizeof(TABLE));
newO->orders = (ORDER*)malloc(10*sizeof(ORDER)); 
...
newO->orders[0]->quantity = qty;
```

...although to be honest, it's hard to tell whether `orders` were really meant to be an array.

Comment: @haccks: He doesn't have the privilege allowing him to vote yet :)